# Why does Boolean difference add material to this mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

In Blender 2.76b and 2.79b, in a mesh, I have added a Boolean subtract modifier. The subtracting mesh was made from text. I have another mesh from text which subtracts correctly. However, on this one, instead of only subtracting the volume, it also adds an outline where the modifying mesh (from text) exceeds the modified mesh.

Here is a screenshot showing the modified mesh in edit mode:

[image: Modified mesh in edit mode.]

Here is a screenshot showing the modified mesh, in which you can see that the subtracted mesh (from text) somehow also adds:

[image: Modified mesh in object mode, showing added material from subtract operation.]

I mirrored some of the vertices in making the modified mesh, because the shape I am making is symmetric. Mesh from text subtracts correctly on the first side which I modeled by hand. However, mesh from text (whether I duplicate the first text or create new text) adds as well as subtracting on the mirrored side.

Does the mirroring have anything to do with this? How can the issue be resolved?

[Here is the .blend file.](http://eaglegamma.com/public/goggles/goggles-text.blend)

Thank you!

Comment: Hello :). It might be useful if you [shared your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Comment: I would recommend you update to at least Blender 2.79, as many of these kinds of glitches were solved in the later updates.

Comment: I added the .blend file to the description.

Comment: I was using an older version of Blender for compatibility with another computer on which I modeled these. I will look into this on a later version.

Comment: Problem still there in 2.79b. @Nate_Sycro27

Comment: Added the .blend, forgot to notify @JachymMichal

Comment: Found a resolution, using a different Solver in a later Blender version. Thanks @Nate_Sycro27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the "Carve" Solver. When I switch to "BMesh" in Blender 2.79b, it seems to produce the correct output. Thank you for providing ideas!

Comment: Still seems to pose an issue in some cases, even using "BMesh".